# Reporting Service on SP 2013 use a sql 2012 report server running as native mode?

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, reporting-services

Sharepoint Reporting Service Integration has to be done with a report server running on SP integration mode? Is this true in SQL2012 + SP2013?

I have a SQL2012 Report server which is in Native mode and being used by other applications. Now, I have a SP server and want to deploy SSRS reports directly to this SP. In SQL2012 Report server configuration, we can only choose run as Native mode. When I configure Reporting Service on SP, can I still use this existing report server (which is in native mode)? or, have to setup another report server?

thanks

Comment: Is there a reason why you want to deploy your reports to SharePoint rather than the existing Report Server? The safest option might be to just have a new instance of Reporting Services running SharePoint integrated, and have your existing applications still working fine in a 'legacy' kind of set up.

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out. the answer is no, we do not have to use another reporting server, SP does all. So, if the SQL reporting service (native mode) and SP are on the same server, you can keep the native mode and run SP with integration mode at the same time.